# Where() in (select) H2

Tags: java, mysql, h2

I have 2 kinds of software (both Java): One with MySSQL and the other with H2 database. My problem is that in MySQL I have this query:

```
Select * from X where (1,2,3) in (select 4,5,6 from Y)
```

But in H2 throw me this error:

> Subquery is not a single column query; SQL statement:

I understand basically what this mean but I need to select all values from X that are in Y and I read that this is the most efficient way. The other way could be asign all the values from Y to a Java Object and then put them in to X but I know that this is not the "best" way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to modify the query to have single values

```
Select * from X where CONCAT(1,2,3) in (select CONCAT(4,5,6) from Y)
```

So instead of 3 columns you have one where all the 3 column values are joined

Comment: That might return wrong results, e.g.: `concat(12,1,12)` would match `concat(12,11,2)`

Comment: It's just the idea. We can add anything in between e.g. `_$$$_` to have `1_$$$_2_$$$_3`

Answer (score 3):

FYI version 1.4.200 seems to support this now