# Hibernate generating invalid code? Database doesn't support multi-column subqueries

Tags: hibernate, orm, h2

I am using Hibernate 5.2.9 and H2 Database 1.4.196 (both are the latest or fairly close).

One of my *Criteria Queries* is generating this SQL:

```
select count(*) as col_0_0_ from ListingDetailBaseDto listingdet0_ 
where listingdet0_.ListPrice>=500000 
   and (listingdet0_.ListPrice<=5000000 or listingdet0_.AskPrcLow<=5000000) 
   and listingdet0_.TotBds>=0 and listingdet0_.FB>=0 
   and ((listingdet0_.address, listingdet0_.apn, listingdet0_.city, 
         listingdet0_.state, listingdet0_.zip) 
       in (select address1_.address, address1_.apn, address1_.city,
           address1_.state, address1_.zip from Address address1_ 
           where ? in (select boundaries2_.boundaries 
                       from Address_boundaries boundaries2_ 
                       where address1_.id=boundaries2_.Address_id) 
              or ? in (select boundaries3_.boundaries 
                       from Address_boundaries boundaries3_ 
                        where address1_.id=boundaries3_.Address_id)
           )) 
   and (listingdet0_.Status=? or listingdet0_.Status=?) 
   and listingdet0_.ctcValidTo>? 
   and listingdet0_.UpdtDate<=?
```

That is blowing up with the error `Subquery is not a single column query`. The error is widely documented and is due to general missing support for multi-column expressions in H2. See also [Where() in (select) H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056328/where-in-select-h2).

Now, one of the primary reasons I use Hibernate to begin with is to insulate myself from database engine idiosyncrasies such as this.

How can I tell Hibernate that multi-column expressions are not a capability of this database, and have it generate correct SQL? It could, for instance, use a JOIN instead of the IN subquery.

**Is Hibernate generating invalid code?**

Comment: Hi. Here it would be nice if you block quoted a code block. Also although you are quoting it would be nice if you indented the code since you want us not a program to read it.

Comment: Why is this tagged [relational-algebra] & not [sql] instead?

Comment: I wasn't aware any dialect of SQL allowed multi-column expressions for `in` subqueries. wrt to @philipxy's comment, I'm not sure this q should even be tagged [sql]: it seems Hibernate is generating invalid code. You need to fix the Hibernate expression to not generate multi-column. Is your query trying to match all of `address, apn, city, state, zip` to the same row in table `Address`? Then yes, `in` is the wrong operation, use `JOIN`: possibly `Natural JOIN` -- depending on your overall schema.

Comment: I narrowed down the question to only ask whether Hibernate is generating invalid code, so that I may open a ticket on the Hibernate project. I'm pretty sure this code works in MySQL, of course, that doesn't mean it's valid. I already have a work-around using JOINs.